# Is there an alternative for nested loops in python for when order of values doesn't matter?

Tags: python, optimization

I realize the title is hard to follow, so please bear with me as I try to explain what I mean.

To set the scene:
I have an array (arr) of classes, where each class has 2 values (A and B). I am trying to evaluate which combination of 4 classes has the highest sum of A, while keeping the sum of B below a certain threshold. There can be repeats, "1233" would be fine for example. However, evaluating "3321" after that would be a waste, as the sum of A and sum of B would be the same as with "1233".

The way I'm currently handling it is as follows:

```
for i in range(0,len(arr)):
    for j in range(0,len(arr)):
        for k in range(0,len(arr)):
            for l in range(0,len(arr)):
                total_a = arr[i].a + arr[j].a + arr[k].a + arr[l].a
                total_b = arr[i].b + arr[j].b + arr[k].b + arr[l].b

                if total_a > best_a and total_b < max_b:
                    best_a = total_a
                    best_arr = [i, j, k, l]
```

Needless to say, this way of doing it isn't very good, as there is no difference between adding the same indexes in a different order. Using nested loops like this makes basically the same evaluation 24 times, if my math is correct. My current implementation works, it's just really slow and not optimized at all, so I was wondering if there was a better way to do it.

Comment: If you want speed, you'd want to do that with Numpy – that is, transform the `a`s and `b`s to two flat Numpy arrays, then use Numpy's parallelizable/optimized loops.

Comment: As for the repetitions, you could use `for i, j, k, l in itertools.combinations_with_replacement(arr, 4)`

Comment: sorting the array will allow you to break some loops early, saving a lot of iterations. Start with something simpler, like the sum of only 2 components. Imagine the sorted array [1,2,3,4,5] and threshold 3.  you evaluate 1+1, 1+2, 1+3 (this one is above the threshold so you can skip 1+4 and 1+5). Then you increase the outer loop and start with 2+2 (which is already higher than the threshold, so skip 2+3,2+4,2+5) and so on.

Comment: first, as AKX suggested, transform to `numpy` arrays, but then I suggest use `numba` package to perform the loops.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a possible solution using ortools (Install it using `pip install ortools`)

```
from dataclasses import dataclass

from ortools.sat.python import cp_model

# Data
@dataclass
class X:
    a: int
    b: int

arr = [X(3, 2), X(2, 1), X(5, 7), X(2, 5), X(3, 1), X(8, 9)]
max_b = 7

# Model
model = cp_model.CpModel()

# Variables
C = [model.NewIntVar(0, 4, str(i)) for i in range(4)]

# Constraints
_ = model.Add(cp_model.LinearExpr.Sum(C) == 4)
_ = model.AddLinearConstraint(
    cp_model.LinearExpr.Sum(
        [C[i] * arr[i].b for i in range(4)]
    ),
    0,
    max_b,
)

# Objective
model.Maximize(cp_model.LinearExpr.Sum([C[i] * arr[i].a for i in range(4)]))

# Solve
solver = cp_model.CpSolver()
status = solver.Solve(model)

# Print solution
if status == cp_model.OPTIMAL:
    print("Optimal solution found!")
    print(f"best_a: {int(solver.ObjectiveValue())}")
    comb = ''.join(
        index.Name() * row
        for index, row in solver.Values(C).items()
    )
    print(f"Optimal combination of classes: {comb}")
```

The output from the example is:

```
Optimal solution found!
best_a: 11
Optimal combination of classes: 0001
```